I added DNS records to my domain it made my website unavailable in Iraq
I was trying to set up authentication to my web app using Clerk auth(clerk.com). I completed the production instance of my authentication project and added the CNAMEs required by them to my own domain(decorty.store), and then the issue happened. The issue wasn't with Clerk itself, it was that my website is now unavailable for users from Iraq. Please assist me in getting my website available in Iraq again. Note: It's been two days since removing the records from my DNS records list.
I'm using Vercel to host my website.
The most obvious solution was to remove the records and it did nothing even after two days. I also made sure to make my website a blank page that just sends Hello to a request. I tried using Cloudflare and Vercel nameservers and both didn't solve the issue.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's quite interesting. I don't think adding those CNAME records caused your website to be unreachable from Iraq. I'm not very familiar with hosting, but did you test it here: https://dnschecker.org? It shows DNS records from various countries. But maybe there are some issues with your computer/browser/network? I am from europe (not iraq) but works absolutely fine for me.
Sometimes, global nameservers take longer to refresh data, and maybe the ones used by visitors from Iraq still have the wrong CNAME, which should resolve with time.
Do u know what people from iraq see if they access the site?
P.s. maybe its a issue somewhat with www? Did u add www using a cname or A?

From Googling around, it seems that at least one other person has mentioned that Vercel is blocked in Iraq. It's possible that when updating your DNS records, you unintentionally disabled your CDN. This could especially be the case at the point you moved your DNS off of CloudFlare, since CloudFlare offers their CDN service only when you use their nameservers for your site's DNS.
The fix, then, would be the following:

Move your nameserver back to CloudFlare, if it isn't there already

Click the "orange cloud" next to each of your A and CNAME records that point to Vercel.


That way, Iraqi users will connect to your Vercel site indirectly through the CloudFlare CDN which is not blocked, rather than connecting directly to Vercel and getting blocked.
